# 405 error on server (not during local tests)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sql-delete

After testing my application on the live server I get 405 error when I try to delete records:

```
Request URL: http://ijsbrekerz.xxx/api/cards/10
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 185.xx.xx.xx:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Everything else works fine, I can create cards and edit them. Only deleting is a problem.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

In my api I define a route for deletion:

```
Route::delete('/cards/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CardController@destroy');
```

The controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $card =  Card::find($id); 
        
           
        if ($card->picture != 'img/profile/default_avatar.png'){
            
           $picture_name="storage/".substr($card->picture,30,) ;   

            File::delete($picture_name);   
        }

        return Card::destroy($id);
    }
```

Called form a view component:

```
deleteCard(id){
            if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
                fetch(`api/cards/${id}`, {
                    method: 'delete'
                })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    alert('Card removed');
                    this.getCards();
                } )
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
```

Route is in the routelist:

```
        | DELETE    | api/cards/{id}             |                         | App\Http\Controllers\CardController@destroy                               | api
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using:

```
axios.delete(`../api/cards/${id}`
```

instead of

```
fetch(`api/cards/${id}`, {
                    method: 'delete'
                })
```